# 10 inch spider near Mexico City

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Four years ago I found a spider so big that I'll never forget. Unfortunately I don't have a picture but I guess there isn't a lot of big spiders in Mexico. So here are some things I remember:

- It wasn't a brown spider, I think it had red legs with some parts black and others white.
- Its legs were skinny and very long
- The main body was tiny compered with the spam of its legs.
- I found it at noon, after I moved to my new house. Unfortunately it wasn't moving when I found it
- The spider didn't have any visibly hair.

That's all I can remember. I know that this may be impossible but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

It almost definitely wasn't 10 inches, but there are some pretty big spiders in Mexico. There is a species of spitting spider with a 9 inch legspan but it lives in South America not Mexico.

*[Scytodes globula](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/424379-Scytodes-globula/browse_photos)*

[image]

[image]

The cellar spider has a legspan of up to 3.6 inches and a comparatively small body with long skinny legs and no visible hair, but I can't see how that would be confused for 10 inches.

*[Pholcus phalangioides](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/67328-Pholcus-phalangioides/browse_photos)*

[image]

The giant crab spider fits that description to some degree. It has a legspan of up to 4 inches.

*[Heteropoda venatoria](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/48765-Heteropoda-venatoria/browse_photos)*

[image]

The golden silk spider is very large with long skinny orange and red legs.

*[Trichonephila clavipes](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/904336-Trichonephila-clavipes/browse_photos)*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a Mexican Red Knee Tarantula. they are kept as pets. not dangerous except for irritant hairs which they can project and which can get into eyes.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mexican+red+knee&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlvWuyvLgAhULlhQKHbfrD3IQ_AUIDigB&biw=1431&bih=734&dpr=1.65

Comment: It isn't the spider that I saw, but you made me remember something else.